# Apache handeling SSL requests and passing them through to HAproxy

Tags: apache, haproxy

I am trying to set up as a front end reverse proxy with Haproxy forwarding requests to Apache web servers in the back end. My problem is that I have been unsuccessful in getting it to work with SSL requests using Apache.

I know that Haproxy can not handle SSL requests so I am trying to set up Apache to accept the clients requests on port 443 and forward it to Haproxy which will then pick up and forward the requests to the right Apache back end web server. Has anyone done this successfully? If yes can you provide examples of the Apache and Haproxy config please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have please see the configuration here [link text](http://jango.wordpress.com/2009/06/06/haproxy-and-ssl/)

Answer (score 0):

I use nginx, here is an example nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            break;
    }
}
```

In haproxy.cfg, set:

listen  http_proxy 127.0.0.1:8000